# Splitting subfigures across multiple pages -- but programmatically!

Tags: page-breaking, subfloats

I am using the `subfig` package to make many subfloats in a `figure` environment. It works well, as long as you realize that it tracks the whitespaces within the `float` environment.

It also has an option to split figures over multiple pages using a `\ContinuedFloat` command. This means that once a number of subfigures fill up a page, then you end the figure and in a new page start a figure with this `\ContinuedFloat` command -- and it resumes laying out the subfigures (preserving the counts, etc.)

Note that the usepackage command should be as described, and the `caption` and `captcont` package should *not* be loaded, as it causes undesired redefinitions and incompatibilities.

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}    % don't load caption or captcont

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[First]{\includegraphic{first} } \,
\subfloat[Second]{\includegraphic{second} } \,
\subfloat[Third]{\includegraphic{third} } \,
\end{figure}
```

Then to continue subfigures later (presumably, on a new page)

```
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[Fourth]{\includegraphic{fourth} } \,
\subfloat[Fifth]{\includegraphic{fifth} } \,
\subfloat[Sixth]{\includegraphic{sixth} } \,
\caption{All of my six subfigures}
\end{figure}
```

Nifty! But for this you have to know how big your subfigures are, or how many of them you have. I have potentially 30 or 40 or 100 subfigures that I would like to lay out in an array on a page, continuing over into the next page. Also based on the dataset, the aspect ratio of the images maybe different and some will have 5 images per row, and others maybe only 3. These are basically the results from data analysis of some images, and I am producing the tex file programmatically.

Main question: Is there a way to detect that after N subfigures the page is full, and to continue the remaining subfigures in a new page?

Or any other suggestions on how to deal with this issue are also welcome!

Comment: This is the sort of thing that LaTeX typically isn't very good at, although in principle it shouldn't be that hard. (Also imagine automatically switching from a floating table to a longtable.) No solution from me at the moment (I'm marking assignments) but I'm interested to see what turns up.

Comment: I guess the simplest way is to use separate figures, not subfigures. And you can modify the headers/footers, and the figure number output.

Comment: Shouldn't both "split" examples have a caption? The answers are assuming the first caption isn't necessary, which makes the whole problem much easier `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the innput folks. Now, without wanting to break compatibility with loaded packages, I managed to produce a working solution. I digged into the **graphicx** manual and found that `code`\includegraphic[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,keepaspectratio=true]{graphic.png}`code` would basically create a virtual grid of 3x5 rows & cols in which the images would be placed. When the page fills up, my program inserts a `code`\end{figure}\begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat`code` and continues writing out the subfloats. However, this isn't a true multi-page self-breaking figure env, is it?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Why not redefine the `figure` environment so that your `figure` environment can be multi-page and accept captions. This of course ignores the `t`, `b`, `h` options:

```
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
  \def\@captype{figure}%
  \par\nobreak\begin{center}\nobreak}
  {\par\nobreak\end{center}}
```

I am actually writing a package that redefines `float` from LaTeX and uses some of the code offered by the `framed` package so that a floating environment such as `table` or `figure` can be more than a page. I should be able to upload it to CTAN by the end of the weak.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the framed package here. It's probably the best option if you're not going to go the floating route.

Comment: @vafa-khalighi I like this idea. The result ought to be to produce a 'mode' so that the user keeps supplying images, and latex keeps placing it in subfigures -- and beautifully, like latex is good at. That would be in keeping with the what-you-see-is-what-you-mean modality -- and rather usable! Looking forward to your package. What is it called?

Comment: This seems to hide all the captions when using the `subcaption` package.

Answer (score 3):

do not use floats, it makes it easier to allow linebreaks. Here is an example which uses only the small package `capt-of`, which only defines one command and changes nothing in using floats. The counting of the subfloats can also be done by a subcounter, if you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\newcommand\Image[3][]{%
  \tabular[b]{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\\
    #3
  \endtabular}
\begin{document}

\Image[width=0.3\linewidth]{first}{a) First} \,
\Image[width=0.3\linewidth]{second}{b) Second} \,
\Image[width=0.3\linewidth]{third}{c) Third}

\Image[width=0.3\linewidth]{forth}{d) Forth} \,
\Image[width=0.3\linewidth]{fifth}{e) Fifth} \,
\Image[width=0.3\linewidth]{sixth}{f) Sixth}
\captionof{figure}{All of my six subfigures}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does produce an 'array' of images, but it has a few problems. The user should not be producing the (sub)captions, latex should. Not producing subfigures takes away all the features of (sub)referencing, caption formatting and justification that **subfig** offers. While a low-key option, I guess this is not a good enough replacement. Also, I ran the code (replaced \linewidth by \textwidth) but still could not span the whole page. I'm not sure I understand the "{@{}c@{}}" in **\tabular**.

Comment: It is an example of how it can be. And everything can be done by LaTeX, as I already pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old thread, but I recently created the package `figureSeries` which may be a good answer here, you can find it at http://github.com/thomasWeise/figureSeries.

The package `figureSeries` provides

1. a facility to include an arbitrary number of (potentially differently-sized) sub-figures into a figure*-like construct,
2. the ability to make this figure*-like construct look as if it was a floating object, which
3. works well in both single-column and double-column documents.