# Conversion XeTeX -> EPUB

Tags: xetex, conversion

I've got (Xe)TeX document.
It s fine to compile into PDF.
However, I'd like to know how can I do to export it into EPUB in order to read it with my Sony Reader. I've tried to use many tools such as Calibre to convert from PDF to EPUB, but the conversion is extremely bad...

Thank you

Comment: When it is for personal use, my favourite thing to do is to use a template I've set up for the dimensions of my reader (in this case a Sony PR-650 or something like that). I then `\input` the raw `.tex` file into the template/master file and run `lualatex` or `pdflatex`.  So far, this seems easier than messing about with trying to get a good `.epub` file (especially from calibre) --- though this will change, I suspect.

Comment: Does this help: [Effort to make (La)TeX eBook-friendly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16374/5764) Is it a duplicate?

Comment: @Jon Very interesting idea. Actually, I use the same reader as you. What do you mean by template? Do you mean that you just use the geometry package according to the reader screen so you can also watch the same pdf very small on your PC screen? Then you import it in your reader? Because otherwise I have no idea how to make a template...  Thank you.

Comment: I posted a (really) basic example of what I do.  It might be useful as a basic starting point.

Comment: (Use LaTeX to produce Epub)[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub] answers the question.

Comment: ConTeXt can [export to Epub](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/epub). Here are two blogs about how to set this up: [A style file for eink readers](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/a-style-file-for-eink-readers/) and [Creating a style file in ConTeXt](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/creating-a-style-file-in-context/)

Comment: @Marco: The blogs you are linking to describe how to setup context to get pdf's in e-reader friendly size. That something different than to generate a real epub (which is basically an xml-format)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right, unfortunately I cannot edit the comment to make it clear that it's two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example (i.e., minus a couple little things I do that aren't relevant to the basic template). I try to maximize the real estate on the screen, so I get rid or headers, footers, and all that.  If you want that stuff, you need to tweak the `geometry` settings some.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}%
\setstocksize{168mm}{118.8mm}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=118.8mm,textwidth=115mm,
paperheight=168mm,textheight=160mm,
noheadfoot]{geometry}

% font stuff here

\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ open, openlevel=1, atend ]{bookmark}

% page set-up, etc., stuff here

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\input <somefile.tex> % this is the file you want on the reader

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, I'll try this example looks nice.

Comment: Hum actually I confirm that this is a better solution than creating an epub. Indeed by reducing the PDF to the reader screen I have a perfect typography even for maths. This is brillant. Thank you jon. ++

Comment: Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 3):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is able to convert from LaTeX to epub. In your system command line:

```
pandoc document.tex -o document.epub
```

However, I'm not sure how many features from TeX it actually support.

Comment: Interesting alternative Pandoc... But sorry I don't understand how to use it. On TeXmaker I try to add the line you gave on the settings but it's not working. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6421260/pandoc.PNG  Did I do something wrong? Thank you

Comment: You should use it from the command line on your system. `cmd` in Windows, but that's beyond the scope of these comments. On [su] you can get the help for that.

Comment: Hum actually I tried Pandoc by curiosity. And it's good working if you have only 1 TeX file. But I couldn't get my full epub by taking my main tex file who has got many "\input{...}" to the other tex files...