# latex and e-readers

Tags: latex-misc

What is a best way of making math pdf files readable using an e-reader? One needs to reduce the number of characters per line, which one can do either by using the A5 paper option or with A4 paper by forcing the line to be 'unnaturally' narrow. But is there a better way, which can be applied to other people's pdf files?

The same problem arises for people with some degree of visual impairmewnt.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  We've had a few questions along these lines before, try taking a look at the answers to those and see if any of them help.  If not, it might be useful to explain what doesn't help with those so people can better answer your question.  You could start with [Use LaTeX to produce Epub](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1551) and follow the linked questions.

Comment: I've done a lot of experiments with screen readers, and found that they can read `pdfs` ok provided there is **no mathematical content**. In files with mathematical content, I've had most success using `tex4ht` to convert the `tex` file to `html` with `mathml`. Have a look at [questions tagged with accessibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility)- would the tag be appropriate for your question too?

Comment: Another approach would be to create a document template that fits the size of the reader; see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53216/8528) for an example.

Comment: See frabjous' <a href="http://people.umass.edu/klement/russell-imp.html">page for Bertrand Russell's <i>Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy</i></a> at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/1324#1324

Answer (score 4):

It is not very natural to go from a LaTeX document to an ereader (e.g. epub) file. The reason is that LaTeX documents (such as PDF) already specify a lot of information, i.e. they are typeset. Whereas ereaders handle a much more plain-text format in order to change the font size etc.

However, this same problem occurs when converting a LaTeX file to HTML. This problem has also largely been overcome. Which I why I would recommend you to compile your TeX file to a HTML file using e.g. [HyperLaTeX](http://hyperlatex.sourceforge.net/). From here it should be easy to convert to a ereader format using one of the many ereader creators, e.g. [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) or [MobiPocket](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/downloadsoft/productdetailscreator.asp).