# Are there any open research problems in the world of TeX?

Tags: tex-core, big-list, latex-misc, research

For a year-long capstone project in computer science, I have to do some 'original research.'  I'm still not entirely sure what this entails, but it just struck me that perhaps I can do research and simultaneously help the only open source project I truly believe in.

Are there any open problems in TeX or LaTeX that I could attempt to solve over the course of a year?

If possible, one problem per answer. (Note you can still post multiple answers.)

---

To clarify, I'm *not* looking for ideas that would make cool packages per se.  I'm not looking to add some neat package on CTAN; that isn't nearly fundamental enough.  I'm not even looking for high-scale programming project either; those are things you can just truck through (with the possible exception of a BibLaTeX style editor; I understand that's a doosie).  I'm looking for problems that

- have (or need) a clear definition of the problem
- are fundamentally applicable to the *core* of TeX's typesetting (To clarify, I'm not *expecting* to re-code TeX for this, but it's not out of the question.  The 'rivers' problem may have to lead to this, whoever does it.)
- are within the scope of an undergraduate/graduate final year.  (I go to a weird school; we have some pretty amazing research going on at the undergraduate level.  See [the project's official specification](http://www.smcm.edu/mathcs/student-resources/smps/), keeping in mind that each department has its own spin.)

---

I ended up going with 're-evaluating and improving Knuth-Plass for modern hardware' as my proposal, and my adviser was enthusiastic about it (at least upon realizing I wasn't wanting to extend the *language* of TeX).  So I began my research and, lo and behold, it's [already been looked at](http://bowman.infotech.monash.edu.au/~pmoulder/line-breaking/holkner-multiobjective-linebreaking-paper.pdf)!  (This isn't surprising, but it's definitely depressing.)  Perhaps this algorithm could be implemented in one of the newer TeX engines, but that is beyond the scope of CS research.  (For example, it could be applied to avoid rivers and stacks, to improve pagination, etc.)  Thanks for all of your suggestions!

Comment: To those voting to close, please leave a comment saying what your reason is.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I think it is more of a meta question so migration.

Comment: @dustin: Meta is only for questions about this website, not for questions about more abstract aspects of TeX.

Comment: Although I enjoy the question, I voted to close because I think it's too broad. Perhaps is could be narrowed down a bit.

Comment: I really wanted to answer "yes" but the system (and even our moderators:-) get cross with me for one word answers.

Comment: C'mon people, the 24 upvotes and 5 stars at the time of this writing should be enough to tell you not to vote for close!

Comment: Might be interesting in this context: [Guidelines for Future TeX Extensions](http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/475-e-tex)

Comment: I should ask questions half-asleep more often! Wow! @Jubobs I feared so as well, which is why I edited in the 'one answer per problem' idea; I believe it helps give people more of something to work with.  Since there is no *one definitive open problem* with TeX, I'm going to leave this open for a while (ie until the start of term) and accept the highest-voted one with the needed aspect of original research.

Comment: @Marco excellent link! I will have to give that a read when I'm off the clock this evening---it looks like there may be quite a few problems that I could consider. (... and possibly some that the brave may reword here?)

Comment: You mean, other than the glaring problem that it's a completely idiotic design when regarded as a language, aside from its typesetting effect?

Comment: @Kaz Those are pretty harsh words (especially around here `:-)`), but it's a decent point. Frankly, I don't konw how else it *could* be designed and, even if I did, that would be *wayyy* outside the scope of this project.  It took the venerable Don Knuth *several years* to do it the first time, and he is is a much smarter man than I.

Comment: @jake this question has no correct answer and is discussion based. That seems to fit meta more than the main site.

Comment: @SeanAllred Well, he will continue to be smarter man than you so long as you continue to assume that as a fact, whereas he doesn't. :) Knuth is not a deity. Knuth has failings, such as his obsession with all that is low-level and arcane. He's basically a much more erudite version of Mel (the "Real Programmer").  If you want to know some clever way to twiddle bits, Knuth is the reference. Come on, when has Knuth ever worked on a large team software engineering project, know what I mean? (Other than "by proxy", via his books being looked up).

Comment: @dustin See this [meta question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3746/what-exactly-defines-too-broad-of-a-question) about this.

Comment: @Kaz The worst part is you described me---I have a reputation for being [*that* UNIX guy](http://tomayko.com/writings/that-dilbert-cartoon). `;-)`  My point is it's outside the scope, but feel free to post it as an answer to get others' opinions! `:-)`

Comment: @SeanAllred my reason for close was migrate not to stop the question.  I did see your meta question.

Comment: Structured or 'tagged' `pdf` files needs some work for accessibility reasons, as detailed in [Revisiting producing structured PDFs from LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124291)

Comment: Is it "open problems" or "unresolved issues" or "to-do list to improve TeX" or something like "TUG Student/Intership/short-term/long-term projects available" ? May be [Volunteer: upgrade of `amsmath` with inclusion of mathtools into amsmath by AMS](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115462/ignoring-specific-ampersand-formatting-on-a-specific-line-of-an-align-block#comment255874_115462) Just for info: [The (LA)TEX project: A case study of open source software](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-1/gaudeul.pdf)

Comment: @texenthusiast To be perfectly honest, I've been having a hard time grappling the difference myself. Much of CS is so closely related to engineering that it is difficult to meaningfully distinguish the two.  While creating something could be necessary in the course of the project, it should not be the project in and of itself.  (The 'rivers' proposal is a very good example of an existing problem that doesn't yet have a solution even in the *abstract* sense.   Am I making any sense?)

Comment: You are perfectly good, no worries :). May be this Q can throw some ideas for you [What can *I* do to help the LaTeX3 Project](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45838/15717)

Comment: Should this be Community Wiki?

Comment: @JosephWright I believe so, as there is clearly no single good answer, rather a long list of options.

Comment: Possibly Related [What can't TeX do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27440/15717),[Typesetting limitations of LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70901/15717),[What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104248/15717) and [A critique of TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58501/15717), Document [What did TEX do wrong?](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/beebe-2003keynote.pdf)

Comment: and [Are there any disadvantages of TeX being Turing complete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58042/15717)

Comment: How about automatically clearing too many floats? The current situation, we have to manually clear them.

Comment: @PSTikZ While manually clearing them wouldn't be research, positioning them better would be as described in Yiannis' [underloved answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128734/17423).

Comment: @morbusg: The question is overly broad as the answers show: Is it about LaTeX or TeX or ...?

Comment: @MartinSchröder There are several question on this site which have many answers; simply because there are doesn't mean the question is broad. It really depends, but as a general rule of thumb I think it is about the underlying algorithms of the TeX engine---something that would be considered research in computer science (and also in maths, even).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I don't know whether these are open problems or not, but since you are looking for a capstone project, you might be interested to explore if the basic algorithmic aspects of TeX can be improved.

1. **Line-breaking algorithm**. The current line breaking algorithm is a gold standard that all line-breaking software emulate, but is it the best way to break lines? Knuth and Plass's algorithm made specific *premature optimization choices* (pun intended!) like separating page-break from line break, assigning badness based on the raggedness of line but not accounting for rivers, etc. The only real advance since then has been character protrusion, and from what I understand, it still follows the same basic line-breaking algorithm. Now don't get me wrong. I am not saying that these choices were wrong. But a lot of these choices were made because the computational resources of that time could not really handle anything more sophisticated. But now that we have computers that are 1000 times more powerful than those in the 70s, it should be possible to explore other options to see if the line breaking algorithm can be improved by taking into account more factors, especially page-breaking, footnotes, side-notes, and floats. What is better, perfect line breaks but huge vertical spaces to balance the page, or slightly underfull lines but no vertical spaces? There is no way to play around with these in the current framework (please correct me if I am wrong).
2. **Automatic breaking of display equations**. Currently the `breqn` package implements the ideas of Michael J Downes, but AFAIK, the algorithmic aspects are not as well understood as that of line-breaking of text. Is it possible to case line-breaking of display equations as an optimization problem and determine a solution based on penalties and badness?
3. **Parsing *natural math***. There are recurring questions asking if it is possible to automatically translate `<=` to `\le`, `sin(x/y)` to `\sin\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)`, etc. Although it is possible to do so to a varying degree of success with TeX and LuaTeX (e.g., the `calcmath` module in ConTeXt), I haven't seen any work that tries to understand how to parse math without markup. Given how sophisticated the current NLP techniques are, it should be possible to do better than simple heuristics for parsing natural math.

Comment: +1. I think `Automatic breaking of display equations` is the one. `breqn` package still have some issues with it, so I do not use it because of that. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119334/why-does-adding-usepackagebreqn-even-if-not-used-cause-latex-compile-errors, and this is one of the most important problems that needs to be completed. This problem becomes more important to solve when one uses 2 columns class for example, and equations starts to overflow and have to be manually broken. So may be a good project for OP would be to study this package more and make recommendations.

Comment: After giving this the attention it deserves, I agree with @Nasser that 'equation breaking' is a nice, researchable issue.  I also think that improving upon Knuth-Plass with the realization of modern hardware could be an interesting exercise as well---it'd be skirting the line, but I'll ask my supervisor. Thanks!

Comment: See the edit to my question.

Answer (score 101):

I think that the river-problem could be quite interesting to take up on.
I am not 100% sure where this project is in its current state.

[How to define the badness of a river?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29049/how-to-define-the-badness-of-a-river)

But this would be an immense improvement to TeX capabilities (and a quite interesting mathematical challenge, I think). @Raphink has looked a great deal into it, you might consider talking to him if this has any interest.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer so far (when the question is 4 hours old) that meets the 'original research' condition and is doable in a year-long project. A LaTeX debugger (the current top answer) would be great, but it is more of a programming challenge than research. "Writing a LaTeX compiler based on the LLVM Compiler Infrastructure" would be amazing, but would be quite a challenge to complete in a year if you weren't already up to speed on compiler writing (and I'm not even sure it is possible for TeX in this context).

Answer (score 90):

### Typesetting in a fixed baseline grid.

[image: baseline grid]

I know there are few packages that can help on this but it’s still a lot of manual editiong to get the lines on a grid. A fully automated solution, supporting headlines, multi columns, floats, footnotes, margin notes etc., would be great.

**What does that mean? And why is it important?**

Typesetting in a fixed baseline grid means that every single line (or at least the ones of the main text, i.e. sometimes headlines are excluded from that) must stick to a fixed and equidistant grid, that is the same for every page. If the text is interrupted by a figure, a table, an equation, (a headline) or something like that the spacing around this element must be in a way that the following line of the main text lays on the grid again. The main reason for using a fixed grid is that it improves the readability: nearly always the lines form the back of a page shine through and are visible on the front, the more or less depending on the grammage of the paper. If the lines aren’t fixed on a grid, the back lines disturb the visibility and traceability of the front lines.

[image: without grid]

[image: with grid]

For both images I used the same settings (color and blur) for the back verses, but you can see that your eye can follow the lower example (with grid) much better then the upper one. Although this example is a little artificial to demonstrate what I mean, it’s not that much exaggerated …

Beside that it has aesthetic reasons, especially in multicolumn layouts. I simply looks better when the lines of multiple columns stick to the same baseline grid.

[image: without grid]

[image: with grid]

An for that **using a fixed grid is considered as good typography**.

Image source: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundlinienraster

Comment: But even Markus Kohm (see: http://www.komascript.de/gridset ) did not succeed with gridset. And a large publishing company in Germany for legal stuff stopped (as far as I know) experimenting with gridset.

Comment: @KeksDose: I know Markus’ work on that and it’s sad that it doesn’t work completly (yet) …

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more? I don't understand it from just the image...

Comment: From my understanding of this answer, it's talking about setting type on a fixed line height grid. If that's a correct interpretation, here are a couple of links from web typography that address similar issues: http://lamb.cc/typograph/ and http://webtypography.net/Rhythm_and_Proportion/Vertical_Motion/2.2.2/

Comment: Isn't this solved in ConTeXt?

Comment: @Canageek: Sure, see my edit. ps. Sorry for the late reply ;-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I don’t know, I never used ConTeXt, but I guess it does.

Comment: @Tobi I had to look into it more, but [ConTeXt does solve this problem](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/showgrid) (I don't know how or how suitably).  Thanks for the explanation!!  I feel like I've learned something :) Given that ConTeXt is just a format, I wonder how it solves this problem.

Comment: @SeanAllred: Grid typesetting requires that you do not use any vertical glue anywhere, and adapt anything this is bigger than lineheight (section headings, floats, etc) so that their height is a multiple of lineheight. Grep for `\ifgridsnapping` in the ConTeXt files.

Comment: @Aditya I think that 'not using any vertical glue anywhere' is a bit harsh; all that truly matters is body / environment text (not sectioning content if I'm correct).  The glue just needs to be 'smart enough' to place content back on the grid.

Comment: @SeanAllred: IIUC, the glue model in TeX does not work in multiples of `\lineheight`. You specify a maximum and minimum strechability and TeX figures out a good value. This get more complicated if the lineheight changes (consider, for example, lines with large math expression). So the only way to get grid typesetting in __current__ TeX is to kill glue completely and manually (well, using macros) take care of the rest. See Chapters 1, 4, and 8 of the [It's in the details](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) manual.

Comment: My humble contribution to the discussion: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf

Comment: @MarioS.E. Good reference and it's good reading but `grid` doesn't always work.

Comment: @Tobi: Did you create the image of the letters shining through the page with LaTeX? Could you provide some information on how you did it? It would be an interesting feature to have a document with a blurred back page in a draft-mode to see how bad the effects would be if the paper is thin.

Comment: @Kubo: No, I did it with Illustrator or Photoshop (can’t remember). Ad hoc I’m not aware of a TeX solution to do this. Maybe some scripting with `pdftk` and/or `imagemagic` could do the trick to … you could create a new question and see if someone has an idea how to implement it in TeX (but I guess, the answer could be, that it is not possible).

Comment: @Tobi: Ok, I did that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444701/how-do-you-get-a-blurred-backpage-in-draft-setting)

Answer (score 51):

In the early 90's I gave a paper on open issues with TeX and directions for research called "E-TeX: Guidelines to future TeX extensions" and just last year I revisited it and presented a paper in Boston on the current status of the original problems identified: [E-TeX: Guidelines for Future TeX Extensions --- revisited](http://latex-project.org/papers/tb106mittelbach-e-tex-revisited.pdf). In there you should find some ideas I hope.

Maybe a word of caution, when looking through some of the suggestions in the answers: some are fairly trivial and some could gain you a PhD and it will not be always easy from the outside to say which belong in which category. So when you start zeroing in on anything get advice on what you are in for ;-)

Comment: +1 for not leaving iTeX (bing) out of the figure. :) I'll add this to the very top my growing reading list on my desk.

Comment: @Frank Mittelbach: Your warning seems appropriate. So easy to choose the wrong project. You have how many years experience with TeX? 20? More? So would you mind to appraise the suggestions here, one by one, by giving a short comment to each (ok, nearly each) of them! Especially if mine were easy or impossible to realise, I'd be very glad to know that. Probably the lot here as well is curious.

Comment: @KeksDose frank’s had more than 20 years’ experience, i think.  i started in the late 80s, and by the time i got to look at other people’s stuff, frank was already in the list.

Answer (score 40):

#### A LaTeX (macro) debugger

Amongst some unmentionables, it could allow one to step through one's code sequentially in order to identify macro arguments and contents, thus avoiding the use of `\typeout` and `\def`-to-`\show` for verification, or making sense of the sometimes elaborate [tracing function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60491/5764) output.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124880/8528) might be useful for anyone interested in (working on) this problem.

Comment: Isn't pdfTeX in C? I feel like this wouldn't be too bad to do. (Not immediately recognizeable as original research, but definitely worth looking into for anyone looking for a project.)

Comment: Not that there's any good answer there at the moment, but maybe watch [tools - How to best debug LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-best-debug-latex) .

Answer (score 39):

If you typeset a document page by page, almost anything is possible. Most of the difficult problems in LaTeX have to do with the automating production of documents.

A problem in seek of an algorithm is the placements of marginpars (especially with a view to  include figure captions in margins).

[image]

This image from  [Unusual graphics and caption placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54065/unusual-graphics-and-caption-placement), has no solution so far (I have accepted the answer out of courtesy).

**Problem Definition**: If an image extends into margins allow captions to float to the previous page or to the forward page.

In general marginpar placements are problematic and LaTeX's algorithm is in need of improvements. This problem in a way extends the pagination algorithm of Knuth-Plass and should be interesting both from a purely Computer Science perspective as well as coding. 
(Caveat: It might take longer than a year).

Answer (score 34):

### Make accessible PDF documents that conform to standards

Figure out how to make PDF documents that:

2. [Can be read out loud by a PDF reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76027/accessibility-issues/128097#128097), and
3. [Can be reflowed automatically for different screen and font sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579/how-to-create-tagged-pdf), and
4. [Pass automated tests for accessibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124291/revisiting-producing-structured-pdfs-from-latex)

using just core TeX, and without requiring the author to do anything other than compile the document.

See some of the questions tagged [accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility) for examples of the issues.

Comment: Point 2 is probably outside the scope of PDF.  That would be something for an Ebook, but a reader/format with TeX's expressiveness has yet to be released, so it will never be perfect and may never be decent. Point 1... point 1 is possible, but it isn't research. :(

Comment: Somebody *really* needs to get on these though; perhaps this is a project for next summer.  (Or perhaps Google Summer of Code?)

Comment: Please do this with ConTeXt; it's much easier than with LaTeX.

Comment: Isn't point 1 same as creating a tagged pdf document? That is already possible (out of the box in context, and I think there was a package for it in latex).

Comment: Yes, point 1 is about creating a tagged PDF document. While it's possible in context, that's not core tex (or latex) and PDFs generated with the latex package ([accessibility.sty](http://www.babs.gmxhome.de/download/da_pdftex/accessibility.sty)) don't pass the automated tests.

Comment: @LostBrit: What do you mean by ConTeXt is not Core TeX. ConTeXt is a macro package written on top of TeX, and it is as much of core TeX as LaTeX. Did you mean that ConTeXt is not as popular as LaTeX? However, that does not change the fact that generating tagged pdf is *not* an open problem in TeX world.

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned that he was looking for things that could be implemented in core Tex or LaTeX. So, that's why I said that Context was not LaTeX. Now that the focus of the question seems to have become typesetting, I don't know that accessibility is relevant, regardless of the flavor of macro package that one uses :(

Comment: @SeanAllred - some reasonable subset of HTML5 might well make a good target for a Tex engine that aims to support reflowing.  Javascript allows work arounds for some of the deficiencies of HTML.

Answer (score 30):

### Using LaTeX to render e-books

I prefer reading documents on the tablet for some time now, basically because I don't have to carry around paper (and because I don't usually annotate even printed documents). However, most PDFs around are prepared for printing, and have to be zoomed to be read on the tablet.

It doesn't seem to be too simple even to manually generate e-book friendly versions of existing LaTeX documents, see [Effort to make (La)TeX eBook-friendly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16374/8057) and [Creating Kindle-friendly versions of existing LaTeX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1632/8057). It might be challenging to create a fully automated solution that provides the beauty of LaTeX typesetting to a mobile device with its particular screen dimensions and the font size chosen by the user.

Some ideas:

- An input filter to [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) that accepts ePub and other popular formats, perhaps FictionBook.
- A robust preamble (that includes [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype)), adjustable to screen dimensions and with the ability to choose font size. Or, automatic choice of font size so that a line has a user-defined number of characters on average, say, 62.
- Robust compilation of any (syntactically correct) input without overfull boxes -- it's good enough if the output looks perfect only 99% of the time. Possible solutions: Scaling of overly wide contents or allowing for very sloppy breaking *where necessary*.
- Images pre-rendered at the resolution of the target device.
- Splitting the document into pages is fine -- books do have pages, too.
- Output is a PDF that just fits the screen of the target device, perhaps with navigation buttons as in the beamer or pdfscreen packages.

For the sake of completeness, references to questions that ask for conversion "the other way round":

[LaTeX document to epub or mobi ebook formats (with mathematical formulas)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16569/8057)

[Conversion XeTeX -> EPUB](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53212/8057)

Comment: FWIW, ConTeXt can generate epub out of the box (including translating math to mathml). See [ConTeXt wiki article](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/epub) for details.

Comment: I think "render" is the wrong verb here.

Answer (score 23):

## Make LaTeX a modern programming language

I'm not an expert on LaTeX like some of the people here, but I have many times run into LaTeX's limitations compared with modern programming languages (that I am very familiar with). I believe that in the long term, LaTeX should not be a macro language for exactly the reason that it is very hard to apply the straightforward programming concepts that other languages take for granted: abstraction, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic programming, etc.

### Memoization of section compilation

Why is the whole document recompiled every time?  Why can't some of the work for each paragraph (or section or figure) be kept if the context (font, spacing, block width, etc.) in which the paragraph is recompiled does not change?  LaTeX should memoize the result of compilation for each section based on the context in which it is compiled.  This would eliminate the need for breaking your document into various tex files and recompiling them yourself (doing the job of the compiler), and it would supplant `tikzexternalize`.

### Context-based symbols

Allow LaTeX “macros” to be programs that interact with the context in which they're invoked.  I think there are problems with footnotes in captions, or footnotes in table notes.  I don't remember, but I know I've run into them.  My guess is that these problems would be mitigated by having both the context in which something is invoked (table, bibliography, figure caption) and the embedded element (footnote, another figure, etc.) be able to answer questions to each other to come to some conclusion about how to be rendered.  I don't understand `\protect` and `\DeclareRobustCommand`, but hopefully this would eliminate them.

### Full programming abstractions

Many of my diagrams are coded in Python that generates Tikz code.  Tikz looks great, but its programming features are severely limited compared to the freedom you have in Python.  Even if you *can* do something, it is hard to read and hard to debug.  Wouldn't it be great Tikz were a Python module?

### Type safety

So many errors can be avoided by ensuring that when a color is requested, it is in the right format xcolor, `#122314`, and so on… Regular programming languages can verify the types of their arguments.

### Debugging

It would be much easier to write a debugger as Werner suggests if LaTeX were a regular programming language.

## Suggested approach

My suggestion would be to make a Python module that implements the various internal latex compilation routines.

### Programmatic access

This module would provide programmatic access to a “latex context object” and a “compiled latex element”.  Inspecting these would let you see all of the relevant settings in relevant subobjects.  This would be much more useful than any LaTeX debugger.

### Early versions are still useful

You don't have to worry if you can't complete a whole latex replacement.  Even the early versions of such a module would still be very useful.  Just a module that provides pythonic access to Tikz would be extremely useful to me.

### Debugger

Python already has a great debugger.

### Speed?

Python already has the ability to transparently incorporate fast C++ versions of methods, and with development of pypy, regular python may one day be comparable in speed to hand-coded C++.  Anyway, the benefit of cached compilation far outweighs faster compilation in my opinion.

### LaTeX macros should be regular Python objects

Besides Python's excellent object model, it has amazing metaprogramming facilities.  If you ever find yourself writing the same code twice, in Python, you don't have to.  It can be very useful to write code that writes code.

I doubt that latex module development is not hampered by the fact that everything is a macro.  Take a look, for example, at [tikz.code.tex](ftp://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex).  Try to make sense of anything.  This code looks like it was written 30 years ago.  Software engineering has come a long way since then: encapsulation, abstraction,… separation of concerns.  You don't realize the value of these things until your code is a couple thousand lines and you can't keep it all in your head.  Imagine how much faster latex modules would be developed if it were a modern programming language.

### Separation of syntax from compilation

All of this can be done without deciding what LaTeX code should look like.  Someone can use the Python module to interpret existing LaTeX code, or design a new variant of LaTeX code.  Other people can use the Python module directly within Python to generate figures or programmatically generate documents.

Comment: It'd be an interesting exercise, but not original research (as I understand it; my understanding is, admittedly, not very firm).  But you might want to check out [tag:expl3].

Comment: @SeanAllred I have no idea, but `expl3` looks like it is still a macro language?

Comment: At its core, yes; it is still based upon the core TeX engine (with eTeX extensions) based upon macro expansion.  `expl3` is, however, a completely object-oriented language at this point; it's just not implemented as such at the moment.  (I'm ***not*** part of the LaTeX3 team, but I'm working on something that will prove useful for taking advantage of this model: https://github.com/vermiculus/l3obj)

Comment: @SeanAllred: If it's a macro language, then how can it provide regular object-oriented programmatic access to all of the latex elements?  I imagine you'll still run into limitations.  Your project looks very cool.  I think we have the same dream, only I can't see how you will be able to accomplish it working within the restrictive LaTeX environment.  Why not build from the outside-in?

Comment: You're forgetting it's Turing-complete ;) OO is just a paradigm; it's not a quality of any particular language.  I've made a stripped-down OO system in C, but C is of course not OO in itself. 'Why not build from the outside in?' Because virtually *every* existing tool for TeX (e.g. LaTeX) depends on its macro expansion.  You'd be rewriting the system, and [that didn't go very well last time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Typesetting_System).

Comment: `C` is Turing complete, but that doesn't mean that you can implement object-oriented design easily at all :)  `C++` claims to have metaprogramming (with templates), but it's terrible compared to Python.  "Being able to do something" is not worth as much as "being able to something clearly and succinctly".  I think that's one of the motivations of your project, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10182/discussion-between-sean-allred-and-neil-g)

Comment: Seems to me like you want Luatex: it has that programming language and a builtin Metapost interpreter. Lua beats Python in terms of speed any day and there is [Luajittex](https://foundry.supelec.fr/projects/luajittex) for computation intensive tasks. The only thing still lacking is a decent Latex integration.

Comment: @phg: Luatex is definitely a step in the right direction.  Unfortunately, I really think Lua was a poor choice at least for me.  Python has access to all of the numeric and statistical libraries that I use to generate figures.  Python also supports introspection and decorators so that code can write code and convolutions and closures to make simple tasks succint.  Since both Lua and Python are compiled to bytecode, Lua can't be significantly faster and I think bigger returns would come from automatically caching compilation, which no latex compiler does afaik.

Comment: @neil-g The library support should be remedied once the [Luatex swiglib project](http://www.luatex.org/swiglib.html) gains traction. With respect to language features, [neither Lua and Python can be considered a clear winner](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaVersusPython). Also, bytecode or no, [Python’s design apparently precludes some optimizations that are possible with Luajit](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3851#comment-57701).

Comment: @phg: It's true that Lua can optimize some things where Python can't, but that's a small performance win — even if it's twice as fast, it doesn't compare to the benefit of adding a dependency graph to latex and recompiling the bare minimum.

Comment: @phg: More importantly, the only point on the comparison page about Lua being "a better choice" than Python is that it has a small memory and disk footprint.  I don't see how that matters.  I'm not running it on my phone.  People have gigabytes of memory.  Who cares about the difference between 100k and 1000k?  Also, that page was written at least 5 years ago.  Python is developed by a much larger community, which has driven a lot of improvement since that page was written.  Searching stackoverflow, there are 210,000 Python questions and only 4000 Lua questions…

Comment: To your modernization sugggestions, the wizards always reply with this : *Many have tried, many have failed*. You can nevertheless start from the Pascal code and implement it in your favorite language. But I think you are underestimating the the functional advantages of TeX over others for *typesetting*. Word, Open Office etc. are coded in very contemporary tools and we see how things are handled.It would not matter that much (in my opinion) had they been compilation-based-typesetters. Regarding the Tikz details, they are bound to PS, PDF specifications not to TeX.

Comment: @percusse: I love LaTeX.  I love the beautiful reports it generates.  What am I asking for is programmatic access to the internals of the latex compiler and Tikz commands so that I can, for example, automate figure generation.  In other words, I want latex/tikz to be a library (or module) in, e.g., Python.  Right now, I have a Python program that generates tikz code that latex uses to generate a pdf of of my figures.  I'd be happy to show it to you if you are curious.

Comment: I'm using the same workflow via Python however you need to convince yourself that the beauty comes from its unique properties. You can't make a Lamborghini out of a VW beetle. Each of them has been designed for different considerations. And I think you don't need an intro to D. Knuth. He knew about these languages back then too. It's an opinionated system. Maybe Ken Thompson should have taken the project back then :)

Comment: @percusse: If you use the same workflow, then you know how frustrating it is to debug the generated latex file.  Error line numbers have to be traced back to the python line that generated them — not an easy task.  Error messages themself are hard to decipher.  All of this is the result of bad overall design. If we had programmatic access to tikz, we would get errors as soon as we call “line” or “point”.  Immediately checking arguments  would yield more meaningful errors.  Also, I'm sure you know that Knuth did not know about Python when he invented tex 13 years earlier :)

Comment: Yes but you are missing the point that TeX has a programmatic access only not in your expected way. That's a different ball game. You want it to be like Python which is not fair. Regarding TikZ part, it is designed for TeX not Python so again that's a misplaced complaint on TikZ side. Also TikZ specifically does things according to what is possible in PS and PDF. If phython produces Javascript code then according to your argument TeX should understand Javascript

Comment: @percuss: I don't know why it's "not fair"?  We once had only gnuplot, then matplotlib came out giving programmatic access to plotting.  We only have latex now, but I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to have programmatic access to its internals.

Comment: It's mainly because they are different beasts. I don't know how an interpreted language can understand what an expansion based code does.

Comment: @percusse: My point is that neither latex nor tikz need to be expansion-based.  I'm surprised more people aren't sick of this anachronistic design decision :)

Comment: Well, we are but and then what? Again let me remind you *Many have tried, many have failed*. So I'm not even in the league.

Comment: Also it is definitely not anachronistic it's just unpopular. HP calculators used (reversed)Polish notation if you get the hang of it there is no way regular ones can match but would you like to learn it?

Comment: @NeilG: Lua does provide programmatic access to TeX internals. It is possible to directly generate PDF from a Lua program using [ConTeXt Lua Documents](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD). I use that to directly generate documents from XML files (e.g., CV with publications stored in an XML file). The difference between Lua and Python basically boils down to personal preference.

Comment: @NeilG: There are alternatives to TikZ which are closer to a sane programming language, e.g., Asymptote and ePiX. TeX World != LaTeX + TiKZ.

Comment: @Aditya: Did you look at these links?  [1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/66590/why-python-and-not-lua) [2](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaVersusPython)  Python has well-maintained standard libraries.  Lua aims to be lightweight.  I think we can agree that Python is winning the "scripting language war" and more people prefer Python rightly or wrongly…

Comment: @NeilG i have seen those links, but I do not see any compeling reason for favoring Python over Lua.  I agree that Python is more popular and has more features, but that in itself is not a reason to use it to enhance TeX. Popularity is fad. 10 years ago it was Perl, 10 years later it will be something else. In any case this is a useless debate because luatex exists and is sucessful, unlike the umteen other attempts to reimplement TeX in a modern programming language

Comment: @NeilG. BTW are you aware of Luigi scarso's work of embedding Python in LuaTeX? See the past issues of tugboat or Luigi's user page on contextgarden.net

Comment: @Aditya: I feel like we're talking past each other.  I'm not suggesting embedding python (or lua) in tex.  I am suggesting exposing tex as a module in Python.  Did my point above "Memoization of section compilation" make sense to you?  This would be a huge saving in document compilation time for anyone compiling a large document and making small changes at a time.

Comment: @NeilG Luatex exposes tex internals to lua. Lunatic is a two way interface between lua and python. Luigi's uses lunatic to expose python internals to Lua. This shows that in principle lunatic can be used for a two way interface between texlua and python, thereby achiving what you want. Your point about memoization makes sense, but my point is that it can be done using luatex as well. In fact, all the infrastructure is already there in luatex, one just needs to store the node list after each paragraph.

Comment: @Aditya: how do you make it so that only changed paragraphs in a document are recompiled (if only those paragraphs need to be recompiled) using luatex?

Comment: @NeiG: LuaTeX provides access to the node list of each paragraph. In principle, to memoize line-breaking of paragraphs, we only need to add wrappers that store an md5 sum and node list of each paragraph in an auxiliary file, then read the input paragraph by paragraph (luatex provides an input reader callback), check with the md5 sum and if it is the same reload the node list from the auxiliary file and reuse it. It is tricky to make the algorithm robust, but that is independent of using Python or Lua. LuaTeX provides access to all the information needed for implementing any memoization algo.

Comment: Problem is, if you start to change the way TeX works in a backwards-incompatible way (such as changing it into a non-macro language), the whole LaTeX/ConTeXT system won't work because they are written in TeX and they are exploiting all of the macro expansion tricks. Rewriting LaTeX means that the ~4500 packages won't work at all. People who use these systems aren't easily convinced to leave it all. Etc.

Comment: @marczellm: It may be possible to write a tool that allows the old packages to work until replacements that take advantage of new facilities are written.

Comment: @Aditya I doubt that paragraph memoization is that easy to accomplish. For it to work, paragraph building must be referentially transparent. Now consider that there are multiple callbacks that get executed during paragraph creation: ``pre_linebreak_filter``, ``linebreak_filter``, ``ligaturing``, ``hyphenate``, ``kerning``, and (probably, never tried that one myself) ``mlist_to_hlist`` -- these allow injecting arbitrary Lua code, any of which can read from a varying source outside the document, say ``/dev/random`` or the system clock. <continued below />

Comment: ... If you want to memoize you will have to ensure that typeset result depends only on the paragraph material that you feed into your hash function. (Disabling all callbacks might work, but you’d lose all typographic advantages Luatex offers.)

Comment: @phg: ... or ignore such artifacts completely. The purpose of memoization is fast previewing. For the final document, one can always recompile the document with memoization disabled.

Comment: @NeilG "a tool that allows the old packages to work" This means redesigning the TeX language so that it's non macro based, then implementing the full old TeX in the new TeX in order to provide backwards compatibility. Then rewrite LaTeX and all the 4500 packages.

Comment: @marczellm: There must be a way to rewrite TeX so that it still supports packages that are macros while also supporting packages that are expressed in a normal programming language.  This is true because TeX has some internal state and that state can surely be updated without the rigamarole of macros.

Comment: I read through the whole discussion here and have no idea why it is so long. You can **already** use Python code to write TeX packages long ago -- as long as you enable `--shell-escape`. And if you have e.g. Lunatic Python and LuaTeX, you can also access TeX's internal from Python. You "just" need to ask someone who knows TeX/Lua to write the necessary binding libraries.

Comment: @user202729 I don't like that solution. I want TeX itself to be a Python library—not the other way around with Python being callable from TeX.  Doing it your way leads to most of the mess that I described.

Comment: That's possible as well, make a Python module that invokes LuaLaTeX as a subprocess that invokes some Lua code that starts some communication channel, then communicate to Lua regarding what to do and get the result back. It's possible to manipulate the internal TeX nodes from Lua.

Comment: @user202729 Why would you want such a convoluted and brittle solution?  Why not just write TeX as a simple Python library with multiple entry points?  (I feel like most of TeX's problems are caused by poor software engineering design decisions like the one you're proposing.)

Comment: It's called library binding, isn't it? I don't think dropping the interprocess communication part is very important, but TeX is written in C so it should not be too hard to compile it into a dynamically linked library and load it from Python.

Comment: @user202729 Sorry, I think you're still missing the point.  TeX is a horrible macro language.  There's no saving it.  The reason to make it a library is to add a dozen entry points for things like "format paragraph", "format page", "format figure", etc.  Macros should be replaced with object-oriented objects that can query a state object.  These objects should also expose a standard interface to respond to queries about size, placement, stretching, formatting of contents, etc.

Comment: And what I said above doesn't apply? ■ As I mentioned above about internal TeX nodes -- "It is possible to directly access the typesetting capabilities of luatex directly from the lua side without using tex macros" https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376000/250119 -- so if you also start your Lua script with `texlua`, you can typeset a document without ever expanding a single TeX macro. (or so I think. I don't use this myself. The object-oriented part needs some improvement though, I think currently it can only output to one PDF file)

Comment: @user202729 Texlua is a far cry from making it so that "these object should also expose a standard interface that...".  Texlua is still fundamentally living within the tex macro language.

Comment: Can you clarify why do you think that?

Comment: @user202729 Does the answer not do that?

Comment: Are you open to discussion or not? I'm asking you to back up your claim that using Lua to build up TeX nodes is "fundamentally living within the TeX macro language", while it doesn't expand a single macro at all.

Comment: Okay, my point, re-reading some of the comments above. I think that you don't really understand how TeX works and/or how to program in TeX. As a, I have a feeling *something* is wrong, but even though I know how to do everything in TeX now (roughly speaking)  I don't know how it can be improved either. I have some ideas so far to improve the easy-ness of TeX programming -- some is slightly useful, some doesn't.

Comment: @user202729 I wrote a giant answer with all the points laid out, so I don't understand what you want me to explain.

Comment: I made a proof of concept https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665417/250119 on Python API for TeX functions. (for now just \newcommand) Hopefully this can convince you that it's possible to make a good binding between TeX and Python, without rewriting everything (which is what you suggested).

Answer (score 22):

Text streams / parallel typesetting with arbitrary split layouts, full featured multi-footnote and margindata support.
[Not even Context can do it.](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2010/051693.html)
While there are a couple solutions to this, they appear hackish and unflexible to me, and aren’t exactly Luatex aware (please correct me if I’m wrong).

Comment: By "text streams", do you refer to something akin to [`flowfram`](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram)?

Comment: @Werner Like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128574/14066).

Answer (score 22):

#### Breaking the paragraph hold

TeX sets paragraphs as a whole by collecting horizontal lines one after the other and stacking them. These horizontal lists that are stacked usually have the same width. If you wish to break the monotony, `\parshape` comes to the rescue. However, it's very cumbersome to use if you want text to flow naturally from one block to another. Here a block could refer to the break from one column to another, or from one page to another.

An example of this is properly given in  [How to change `\hsize` in the middle of a paragraph at page break, especially for two-column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11166/5764) While the example is given in a two-column document, it pertains to single-column documents with a page break, or multi-column varied-width documents with a page break. Single-page solutions exist; see [Different column widths using `multicol`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89721/5764) and the implementation of [`vwcol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/vwcol).

Ultimately one can use `\parshape` to adjust the shape of a paragraph to flow better from one width to another *within* a paragraph, but this has not been automated AFAIK.

Possible solution 1: A multi-pass approach where the remaining portions of a paragraph is unboxed and reset at a different width, removing any implications of counter stepping or labelling.

Possible solution 2: Construct a paragraph shape iteratively by capturing the available width of each horizontal list being stacked vertically. Reset the paragraph every time there is a change required, until no further changes are required (of course, also taking into consideration that no counters are multi-stepped or labels multiply defined.

Answer (score 21):

#### Parallel Compilation

It's just sad to sit and watch a Quadcore machine spend minutes on a single document, only ever using one core. This is likely to become worse: the trend seems to be towards having more weaker cores (e.g. for better control over energy usage). So, if TeX and friends want to be competetive, arguably, they have to be able to make use of multi-/many-core architectures to some extent.

Since TeX seems to be inherently tied to a sequential execution model (I really don't know too much about it), this may be very challenging or even impossible without changing some aspects of TeX.

Maybe it is possible to quickly assign parts of the stream to pages and filter out parts with global effect, and then lay out pages in parallel? I don't know, but I'd love to see work on this.

Comment: You know, I've never thought of that.  The trend you speak of is very real.  As it sits right now though, I'm not sure it's possible to *adapt* `tex` to a parallel architecture.  I wasn't cleared for research in this area, unfortunately (even with all of these excellent ideas!), but I'd love to read up on the topic to see if this is doable.  I fear the trend toward weaker cores will only continue to isolate TeX.

Comment: You could get a pretty easy setup for this, actually, since TeX already runs multiple times on any document with citations, table of contents, etc. Just start up the 2nd pass while the 1st is still running, but finished the first page.

Comment: @Canageek: I don't know enough about TeX to say that this would work; in particular, are all temporary files (resp. their fragments) written after page one in so far as they regard page one? (I'd guess no.) If that where true, you'd still have to synchronise the runs. That is to say, it's probably impossible to do using TeX as a black box, but it may be a feasible feature for a reimplementation.

Comment: @Raphael You are likely correct; you'd have to modify things a bit, for that reason and to make sure the 2nd pass doesn't catch up to the first, but at a core level it does things page-by-page, so it doesn't seem too hard compared to going into the LaTeX code and working out what can be done in parallel.

Comment: @Canageek: So there is hope! :) One issue, though: given that most documents need <= 5 runs (?) this strategy won't scale to "many-core". I think more time-intensive things need to be externalised, like e.g. TikZ, so that the individual pieces can be compiled in parallel (my [own work-in-progress build-wrapper](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) does this to good effect).

Comment: @Raphael Very true, however, given that most home computers are at most 8 cores, using 4 cores at once would still be a major speedup, and might be a good stopgap measure. I know I'd love even a 2x speed improvement, which wouldn't be hard if I could have latex, bibtex and the second latex pass all going at once.

Comment: [As mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447197/why-doesnt-latex-compile-faster/447199?noredirect=1#comment1123490_447199), it shouldn’t be too hard to lay out paragraphs in parallel using speculative rendering. This would imply discarding and redoing paragraphs if any of its definitions or counters are changed by preceding paragraphs (rendered in parallel), or if its subsequently calculated initial position would imply that it had to be broken across pages or was affected by floats. I think it’s likely that *most* paragraphs would only have to be rendered once.

Answer (score 19):

Implement TeX in TeX. Thanks in advance. `:-)`

Comment: A self-hosting TeX compiler? Is that possible on account of TeX being Turing complete?

Comment: @Jubobs: In theory it's possible. It might be easier to write an llvm backend for TeX to create an emscripten for TeX. :-)

Comment: This would be horrifying.  +1!  It would definitely show TeX's Turing-completeness, but my TeXpert skills are *no where near* the level of *considering thinking about attempting* this. XD

Comment: @SeanAllred: As an aside: [no, it would not](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19667/is-any-language-that-can-express-its-own-compiler-turing-complete). That said, thanks for the brain teaser.

Comment: @Raphael Interesting, and honestly surprising! Thanks for the link!  (**edit:** and apparently, for asking the Q!)

Answer (score 18):

I would like to see more power given to the hyphenation system. Currently, there's just so much you can do with `babel`, like specifying hyphenation for particular words with `\hyphenate{ba-bel}` or `{ba\-bel}`, and the `\discretionary{}{}{}` command.

However, `\discretionary{}{}{}` is quite verbose. And languages such as Portuguese will soon require heavy usage of it. We are just waiting a new set of ortographic rules to be fully implemented in all Portuguese-sepaking countries.

To give an example of how this will be a future problem, translineation of compound words will demand the hyphen to be duplicated when it is involved in the translineation. I'll show this in the following snippet of text:

```
Aqui temos uma palavra como contra-
-ataque que exige duplicação do hí-
fen.
```

Notice how hyphenation happens twice here, but the hyphen in `contra-ataque` is duplicated in the second line of text.

You can obtain that with at least two solutions:

```
Aqui temos uma palavra como con\-tra\discretionary{-}{-}{-}a\-ta\-que
que exige duplicação do hífen.

Aqui temos uma palavra como con\-tra\-\mbox{-a}\-ta\-que que exige
duplicação do hífen.
```

Both are very verbose and break TeX hyphenation (you need to manually hyphenate each of the words in the compound).

Of course, you can defined a shorthand with `\defineshorthand` so you can write things like `"-` instead of the two samples above for compound words. However, this is counter-intuitive and is somewhat troublesome to automatic ortography correction. Not to mention most editors will automatically replace `"` with ``` `` ``` as you type, and you can't defined a shorthand with other characters such as `'-` or simply `-`.

I have seen many attempts to allow text to be normally written with proper translineation in Portuguese, but all seem to fail. I think you'll need to go deep into TeX's core to allow more robust hyphenation rules to be written.

This seems to me like a nice project as it involves not only programming, but also some linguistics research, as it affects many languages besides Portuguese.

Comment: There’s also the idea of preferred and secondary hyphenation points. IIRC, the hyphenation dictionaries being shipped have that information, but TeX has no way to use it.

Answer (score 16):

The idea of a wysiwyg editor for biblatex [Is there a WYSIWYG editor for biblatex styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67248/is-there-a-wysiwyg-editor-for-biblatex-styles) seems like it might make a challenging project. Even a non wysiwyg solution like makebst would be helpful.

Comment: It would be a challenging project (and someone needs to do it). I fear this just may not fly as original research, but I will definitely be asking (about all of these)!

Answer (score 14):

Writing a LaTeX compiler based on the [LLVM Compiler Infrastructure](http://llvm.org/).

Probable benefits would be:

- Much faster compilation
- Lower memory usage
- Expressive diagnostics
- Cleaner separation between [Front- and Backend](http://www.aosabook.org/en/llvm.html)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how LLVM could speed up the compilation? I thought the modern TeX implementations are written in C and interpret TeX files. Which parts can be replaced by LLVM in the toolchain?

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but I imagined one could write a lexer and parser with lex and bison for TeX and then using llvm to optimize the generated intermediate representation.

Comment: Interesting idea (and interesting read; I'm such a nerd), but I fear that such a refactoring of TeX would cause it to become, well, 'not TeX' (according to the TRIP test).  I'll give this a think-over, but I'd have to clear it with my supervisor (since this doesn't *sound* like 'original research').

Comment: @Reza I don't think you can parse tex  with lex/bison as the lexical analysis has to be intertwined with execution. `\foo\catcode\`o=12 \foo` the first `\foo` is one token but the second one is three.

Comment: This is so wrong: You don't need a _LaTeX_ "compiler", but a _TeX_ _interpreter_.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: But do we really *need* code that changes the lexer during interpretation? If we had "proper" abstractions/PL features, could we not do without such?

Comment: @Raphael: What is LaTeX to you? A markup-language or also a programming language?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I feel that there is no good answer. As a computer scientist, I'd like to use it as programming language when writing macros, but when writing the actual document (that happens sometimes) I want more of a markup feeling (like Markdown + macros). So, if I were to design the user frontend of LaTeX, there would be the part where your program (maybe the preamble) with all the nice feature you expect, and all that (and many of the stuff available today) is forbidden during the document (on user level; macros/functions may of course do wicked stuff).

Comment: @MartinSchröder Of course, that would not only enable but force package writers to design proper user interfaces (TikZ comes close even today, imho) which are separate from the implementation. I think that would be a good thing.

Answer (score 14):

## Align floats side by side automatically

Sure, I know that I can use `{minipage}`s to align floats beside each other. But as far as I can see there is no way that LaTeX places two nodes in a row if they are narrow enough.

For example the following code should give two images next to each other automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section*{Current result}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First caption.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is the caption of the second image.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

will arrange the first image above the second one.

[image: above each other]

but the result should look like this

[image: next to each other]

This can be reproduced manually with `{minipages}`s.

```
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{First caption.}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{This is the caption of the second image.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
```

Comment: many funny things with automatic placement of content are possible with luatex, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65601/2891 - I think it shouldn't be hard to achieve what you want with this library

Comment: @michal.h21: Thanks. I’ll have a look at this :-)

Answer (score 11):

Removing the token expansion mechanism from TeX.

### Edit:

In other words, creating an interface or high-level abstraction to let us write TeX code without thinking about the token expansion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You want to write TeX without writing TeX? ;)

Comment: Do you mean, redesign the syntax so it can be parsed without needing to execute the code, and base evaluation on lambda calculus – basically, _functional TeX_? That would sound like a good idea to me, but I suppose it just wouldn't be TeX anymore, but something completely different.

Comment: IMHO, `expl3` is this abstraction.

Comment: [Solved in Luatex](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX).

Answer (score 8):

Rewrite TeX in a modern programming language. Java or C# would be the obvious choices. Tim Murphy tried with [JavaTex](http://www.tug.org/TUG99-web/pdf/murphy.pdf), and his code is available. As far as I can see, the only problem was performance, but computers are faster now than in 1999, and Java is much faster.

The interesting/important parts are:

1. You'd surely learn a lot by reading/understanding code written by one of the world's leading computer scientists
2. You might learn something about software quality -- TeX has a remarkably low density of bugs. Why is that? Partly, it's a result of Knuth's talent and care, I suppose, but maybe there are structural reasons, too.
3. It's a large system, and the re-architecting and modularization issues would be interesting
4. You create a foundation for the future.
5. The rewritten code would be easier to understand (I hope) and more accessible to others who might want to make future improvements.
6. It should be possible to expose pieces of it in a public API, rather than it being a monolithic black box. I guess LuaTex has done this, too, but only for people who like programming in Lua. Something more mainstream would be valuable.
7. You'd (perhaps) need to find/build a modern substitute for web. If so, this would be interesting.
8. The comparison between 1980's technology and 201x technology would be interesting. How do more modern languages and tools and computers change things? Is the job easier now? If so, why?

You don't have to do the whole job (it would be too large a task, I expect). Automatic translation would give you a working mess, and then you could then incrementally clean it up, starting with the low-hanging fruit.

Comment: For a one year capstone project, do not attempt to rewrite TeX. it will take _much_ more than a year.

Comment: Also, C# would be a dismal choice for cross-platform compatibility and Java would be a dismal choice for anything you wanted to actually start `;)`.  Many people have attempted this though, in languages such as Python, but C is simply a better choice.

Comment: (Plus, the day C becomes 'antiquated' is the day I am too old to be in CS.)

Comment: @bubba A complete, functional reimplementation of TeX in Java has been around since the late 90s: [NTS](http://nts.tug.org/). Turns out the various attemps of *evolving* TeX (Omega, pdfTeX) were more valuable than a -- no intention to belittle the work of the NTS authors -- “mere remake” in a different language.

Comment: Please never ever introduce Java to the peaceful world of TeX we have enough problems.

Comment: Re: 8. Why is it that people use the word "modern" to somehow imply "better". Funnily enough, you gain higher level of abstraction with 1980's, e.g. Lisp family of languages than you do with Java. Perhaps even more funnily, it was the same guy who coauthored the Java language specification, as well as (the basis of) ANSI Lisp, *and* Scheme, **and** first port of TeX to ITS, AND lobbied Knuth to make TeX Turing-complete! I don't know what to make of it all, but it sure would be interesting to see a TeX implementation in a very high abstraction level language.

Comment: @morsburg LISP. Then Emacs will clearly be superior to vi.

Comment: @Sean: Oh, you don't want to go there. ;) viper-mode just doesn't cut it.

Comment: @morbusg. Perhaps "modern" was not the right word. I meant something higher level, with improved abstraction; something that does more of the work for you. I guess I don't really care when it was invented. It seems to me that quite a lot of TeX code is just fiddling with bits and bytes to save memory. That's nowhere near as important today as it was back in the 1980's. Getting rid of that stuff would certainly improve clarity. That was (partly) the point of item #8.

Comment: I don't see how cheer-leading for your favorite language or editor contributes much to the discussion. The choice of tools is largely dictated by the tastes and experience of the implementor, anyway. The point is ... if you were implementing TeX today, you probably would not choose to do it in Pascal or C, you wouldn't be so worried about memory footprint or performance, you'd have much better graphics and file I/O tools, etc, etc. In short, the result would be different, and it might well be better in some ways. That's what makes this interesting, I think.

Comment: Sorry, why would you take working code in a fast, low level language and move it to a slower, high level language? TeX complies slowly enough already!

Answer (score 7):

A package for two-column-pages, which allows to print marginnotes for the left column in the left margin and for the right column in the right margin.

Even more important would be a feature to get corresponding »two column footnotes«: Footnotes, which have the footnote mark in the left (right) column are printed below the left (right) column. If a pagebreak occurs, the footnote will be contiued under the left (right) column of the next pages. This refers to text e.g. in the multicols environment.

Binding footnotes to a column would as well be very helpfull for all documents having two *parallel* columns, let's say in English on the left and in Chinese on the right side. Packages: parcolumns, parallel.

And something different: often footnotes are printed in a smaller size, because on each page of a sientific work there is a immense number of references. I'm thinking of jurisprudential books called »commentary« in Germany. However, it is difficult to read a long line in 8pt letters and I sometimes wish I could print my text in one column, but the footnote text in two column mode.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand how you want the footnotes delivered, I could think of two ways to interpret the above statement, but in either case that request appears to me a 1-2 weekends worth of effort.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Encouraged by your patience I edited my suggestion. More or less: any better support of the different mulitcols (parallel, running text, footnote in multicols) would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 6):

## P vs. NP

- Typesetting is for some badness functions in NPC (see iii in [Optimal Pagination Techniques for Automatic Typesetting Systems](https://www.tug.org/docs/plass/plass-thesis.pdf))
- P vs. NP is a [Millennium Prize Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems)

Comment: I think this might be a bit beyond what is feasible for a one-year undergraduate research project `;)` I'll have to read Plass' thesis more carefully; I didn't know it had such theoretical background.  (Then again, he *was* Knuth's supervisee.)

Comment: @SeanAllred: Yes, of course. Nevertheless, I think it is very interesting that Typesetting is NPC.

Answer (score 5):

A multipage tabular environment, which can calculate and display a subtotal in each last row of the page and in the first row of the next page (carry forward).

I suggest to realise it using LuaLaTeX, because calculating in TeX is a pain.

Comment: `pgfplotstable` can do this.

Comment: @percusse I had a quick look through the manual, but without luck: there seems no way how pgfplotstable can notice that a certain row is the last one on this page and therefore a subtotal has to be calculated from the above numbers and printed in that cell.

Comment: @percusse : Subtotals and carry forward are important for business letters and every commercial software can deal with them. I suggested this issue, because to solve it is not trivial: You have to get a hook when TeX writes the last line of a page, and then calculate the subtotal and insert it. I 've been asking around for any solution for quite some years.

Comment: Let's see then :) Can you make that a question? It will probably trigger @DavidCarlisle anyway

Comment: @percusse Later (soccer team calling...)

Answer (score 0):

[Graph Drawing in TikZ by Till Tantau](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-36763-2_46)

Comment: Could you explain why this is a problem (I don’t even understand _what_ the problem is, actually …) so a bit more text would be nice ;-)