# Add content to end of page

Tags: macros, positioning

is there a simple way to add some content at the end of pages similarly to `\AtEndDocument` (for example something like `\AtThisPageEnd`) ?

I looked at `everyhook` and `everypage`, but it doesn't look that it's possible to do it with these packages.

Does someone have an idea ?

Edit: To be more precise, I try to change the layout for some page using the geometry package. I manage to make it work when the textwidth is constant. The problem comes when it is not, see this example

```
\documentclass [a4paper]{article}
\usepackage [showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage {atbegshi}
\usepackage {lipsum}

\title{The Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\geometry{
    paperwidth=18cm,
    paperheight=18cm,
    textwidth=9cm,
}

\makeatletter

\gdef\setGeometryPage
{
    \ifnum\thepage=2
    \global\let\setGeometryPage =\relax
    \expandafter \@gobble % gobble clearpage
    \newgeometry
    {
        textwidth=12cm,
    }%
    \fi
    \aftergroup\setGeometryPage
}

\AtBeginShipout{

    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{
        \setGeometryPage
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First section}

\lipsum[1]
This part is the transition with the next page.
This part is the transition with the next page.
This part is the
%\clearpage\noindent
transition
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Geometry change on page 2, but margin kept to be the one of the first page till end of block [1]]

A workaround (not very nice) is to add the `\clearpage\noindent` at the end of the first page (see example comment).
(NB: I'd like to set the layout only with the `geometry` package here)

Comment: the normal way would be to use `\thispagestyle{zzz}` and then specify your text in the page foot of the zzz style.

Comment: Do  you want the content to form part of the text block, be in the footer, or be added to the shipped-out page at some random position? Could you make it more clear what you're after exactly?

Comment: I agree with @Werner.  If you want it to be still inside the writing area, you could just issue a `\vfill` command and write whatever you want after it.

Comment: @Werner Yes I want it to be part of the text and executed in a macro. For my case I'd like to add a \clearpage at the end of one specific page to begin the next page with a new group.

Comment: Can you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) showing what you have and what you want? The latter should show how to achieve your goal through hard coding, perhaps, even though you want it to be more automated. It would make this more clear in my opinion.

Comment: The “end of a page” is not defined until a page is actually cut off: adding a `\clearpage`, which forces a page break, _at_ the page break sounds like chasing one’s tail.  Or your intent is to flush the queue of floats “at” some page break, without manually deciding exactly _where_ that break should occur?

Comment: Here I edited the initial post with an example of what I try to do.

Comment: @Vin: Ahhh, you've stumbled upon [an open problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129137/5764), where the paragraph layout is fixed, yet you want it to change mid-paragraph (from one page to the next). You'll have to do this manually. Is that option an worth an answer?

Comment: Yep that's why I'd like to split the paragraph in 2 (somehow) just before the pagebreak occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [open problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129137/5764), so you'll have to resort to some manual intervention. Here are two options:

1. Since you *know* where the break is located, you can insert a forced paragraph break and ensure that the last line fills the line width. The length at play here is `\parfillskip`. After that, you can insert your `\clearpage\noindent` like before:

   ```
   \lipsum[1]

   {\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}% Make last line in paragraph fill the line
   This part is the transition with the next page.
   This part is the transition with the next page.
   This part is the\par%
   }

   \clearpage\noindent
   transition
   \lipsum[1-2]
   ```
2. If you don't want to care about the *exact* position, but know that you have a certain number of lines before the page break, you can use `\parshape` to adjust the flow of the paragraph:

   ```
   \lipsum[1]

   \parshape
     3 % Shape of 3+ lines in the paragraph have to be adjusted
     0pt \linewidth % Line 1 = A regular line (no additional indent, and full \linewidth)
     0pt \linewidth % Line 2 = A regular line (no additional indent, and full \linewidth)
     0pt \dimexpr\linewidth+3cm % Line 3+ = Adjusted (no additional indent, width of \linewidth+3cm)
   This part is the transition with the next page.
   This part is the transition with the next page.
   This part is the
   transition
   \lipsum[1-2]
   ```

In both instance above, the following output is achieved:

[image]