# How to split a figure over multiple pages using subfigure package

Tags: subfloats

I am using `subfigure` package and would like to split a figure (that has a number of subfigures in it) into two pages, rather than one single page. I have seen few [posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11059/splitting-subfigures-across-multiple-pages-but-programmatically) about how to do this with `subfig` package and the use of `\subfloat`. But that requires me to change to `subfig` package and change every `\subfigure` to `\subfloat` and so on.

I would be thankful in you guys could help. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/truck1}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/truckLSD1}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/truckEDL2}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/truckDu3}}
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/truckPWA}}    \\ 
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/zebra}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/zebra}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/zebra}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/zebra}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/zebra}}    \\ 
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/office}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/office}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/office}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/office}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/office}}    \\ 
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/micro}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/micro}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/micro}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/micro}}    \subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth]{figures/micro}}    \caption[XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.}
\label{fig:natural}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You should consider using `subcaption` but @AxelSommerfeldt.

Answer (score 4):

To allow continued floats with `subfigure`, use the `captcont` package from the same author.

Please note that both packages has been marked as obsolete by its author, and the successor of both is the `subfig` package which only got a different name because it's not fully compatible with the `subfigure` package.